# Is my proof by induction of even number arithmetic progression correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove that for all integers $n\geq1$, $P(n) = 2+4+6+...+2n=n^2+n$

For $P(1)$, we have that: $2\cdot1=1^2+1$

Let $k$ be an integer with $k\geq1$. Suppose $P(k)$ is true. Then: $2+4+6+...+2k=k^2+k$

I must show that $P(k+1)$ is also true:

$2+4+6+...+2(k+1)=(k+1)^2+(k+1)$ $(1)$

If $k$ is an integer then $l=k+1$ is also an integer. For $l=k+1$ $(1)$ becomes: $l^2+l$ which is of the form $k^2+k$ that is true.

$Q.E.D$

A small change at the inductive step:

I must show that $P(k+1)$ is also true:

$(2+4+6+...+2k)+2(k+1)=k^2+k+2k+2=(k^2+2k+1)+(k+1)=(k+1)^2+(k+1)$

$Q.E.D$

I know that the second inductive step is definitely correct, but I'm confused as to whether the first one is correct.

Comment: I think it's right.

Comment: First one is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the first argument at all.  It looks like you just assumed what you were trying to prove.  The second one looks solid.

Comment: You can't make arguments using equation  $(1) $,as you haven't proved it.

Comment: The first attempt isn't valid.

Comment: You have to **show** $P(k+1):2+4+6+...+2(k+1)=(k+1)^2+k+1$. Just substituting $l=k+1$ and $(k+1)^2+k+1=l^2+l$ does not mean it is proved

Comment: the part with $l$ made no sense, and should just be cut out. if you instead have your inductive hypothesis just be the last part, this is correct.